# How to add datasource - ${host} in yml file dynamically after @Postconstruct code executed

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a method in my code to establish connection with 3rd party and fetch database host url from there,
i have added @PostConstruct to establish connection on startup of application.

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

@PostConstruct
public void establishConnection() {
// here i am fetching details 
// String host = fetched host from 3rd party 
// -----------now i am adding this host to property source-------------

MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
Map<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
propertyMap.put("host", host);
propertySources.addLast(new MapPropertySource("customProperties", propertyMap));

}
```

now when application started i will have **host ** property in application.yml

so that i can access this property like below

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${host}:3306/db_name?serverTimezone=UTC
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: username
    password: pass
```

this ${host} is not populating dynamically from property sources.
i think it is because @PostConstruct code is running after all the bean creation,
and data source bean is getting initialized before @PostConstruct code thats why host is not getting populated.

if this is the case, how to get host before initializing data source

thanks in advance...!